# $V{REPORT_COUNT} isn't working properly

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to limit number of records per page in ireport to 15; I have added a page break and in PrintWhenExpression property, I've set $V{REPORT_COUNT}%15 ==0 but it doesn't work properly, it adds an extra blank page when I have 15 records and displays 16 records when I have less or more than 15 records. The same problem exists when I use $V{PAGE_COUNT} == 15 
I have checked all existing questions but didn't find a solution.

Comment: even this doesn't work: $V{REPORT_COUNT} == 15+(($V{PAGE_NUMBER}-1)*15)

Comment: Not even this: $V{PAGE_COUNT} == 15 &&
$V{REPORT_COUNT} %15 == 0

Comment: But this works better, that is it displays 15 records per page but when I have only 15 records it creates an extra blank page

Comment: Please show a [mcve], that is in jasper include a small example of your jrxml displaying the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:
$V{PAGE_COUNT} == 15 && $V{class_COUNT} != $F{out_max_capacity}

Answer (score 0):

$V{PAGE_COUNT}%15==0 for a page break

Comment: Please set: $V{REPORT_COUNT}%15 ==0 , change: $V{PAGE_COUNT}%15==0 If not ok. please chat skype: quangsang.8x@gmail.com

Comment: I'm still involved with the extra blank page. I added you to my skype Võ Văn Sáng hopefully we can resolve it together